# Find host in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing an app and in a function I'd like to know what is the current host. If I have the request object I've been able to do:
req.headers.host
that returns something like localhost:3000

I am trying to get the same thing, so find out the current host, when I'm in a module that has no request object. How can I know the host with no req object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the request object somehow. There is *no other way*.

Comment: Well it might be possible to get some sort of hostname, but I agree with you nevertheless because that host name is probably not very useful.

Comment: Yes, you would pass the request or just the hostname if that was all that was required to the methods that need it.